# How to replace '&=' with '=&' in Vim?

Tags: vim, substitution

I tried to replace '&=' with '=&' in Vim, but the command `:%s/&=/=&/g`
replaced '&=' with '=&='.

Why did that happen ?
What command should I use ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just escape the ampersand.

```
:%s/&=/=\&/g
```

You need to escape it because `&` is a special character in the replacement that will be replaced with the entire matched pattern.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to escape it?

Comment: As @sharth just said, `&` is a special character. When used in the replacement side of things `&` is replaced with the entire matched pattern. (In your case, the characters `=&`, giving you the unexpected output: `=&=`)

If you want a literal ampersand, just like any special character you have to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: @Caek that explanation wasn't there when I posted the comment. (I know what it does)